# How to close program

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm newbie and I have the following problem
When running the program, the login form will appear for users to log in if successful and the system form will appear

```
formLogin.Hide();
```

But when I close the form the system is still running, how can I fix this.
I tried on successful login but it will close the whole program

```
formLogin.Close()
```

Comment: do you try `Application.Exit()`?

Comment: If `formLogin` is your starting Form, you should change that.You can start your main Form (visible or not), then show your Login Form from your main. If the login proc fails, close your main and the app terminates. Otherwise, go on. If you search SO for *Login Form* or similar, you'll find a lot of similar questions.

Comment: How do I catch an event that closes a form?

Comment: You can show the Login Form as a modal dialog (`.ShowDialog()`): it will return a `DialogResult` value (you can set it yourself to any of the available values). Or, subscribe to the `FormClosed` event: this event is raised when the Form has been closed by any means, but public properties are still readable.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your program is the code `Application.Run`. If you pass a form to that method, then the application will exit automatically when that form closes.

If somehow you wish to explicitly stop your application at some point, use `Application.Exit` to exit the message pump, after which your `Application.Run` method will return and any cleanup can occur.

Calling `Environment.Exit` is the nuclear option that kills the process without prejudice. You should consider whether your application needs to clean anything up as it exits. If so, go for graceful exit.